# JSONP to HTML Table using PLUGIN

Tags: json, jsonp

I want to convert the JSON-P exposed by WCF service to a HTML Table.

For this i am using a plugin:

http://ajaxstack.com/jsonreport/

(THis is a excellent plugin because it handles date very well..)

It has a function:

_.jsonreport(jop);

where jop shoule be a JSON data.

To get the json data i am using jquery get:

To use this:

```
        $.get('http://localhost:1256......', function (jop) {

            alert(jop);

            var test = _.jsonreport(jop);

            alert(test);

        });
```

But i started getting PERMISSION DENIED ERRORS in almost every browser except IE 
(Might be because of cross domain restrictions....).

Can i get complete json using ajax. Actually ajax returns objects not complete JSON

How can i tackle this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using two different projects one for service and one for application in asp.net both application run on localhost with differnet port number and IE does not support cross domain so it throws an error.

So to fixed this i need to combine both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can us typical jsonp for this.  Have you used it at all successfully in not IE browsers (IE being a microsoft prod, allows ur localhost to access xDomain if you've visited and deemed the other domain safe).

If u cannot use regular jsonp, I suggest using flyJSONP/YQL, jankyPOST/jankyPOST techniques.

reg jsonp:

script src="somedomain.com/somepage.json?myCallbackFunction=jsonp" /script

function myCallbackFunction(data){
        return data
}

Hope this helps...